# How estimate a brms model with rpy2?

Tags: r, rpy2

I am trying to estimate the model below. The model uses a package in R called `brms`. I am a doing all the data manipulation in Python. To bridge the two languages I am using `rpy2`. I am able to load the `brms` package with `rpy2`, but I can't figure out the syntax to estimate the model. Below is a simple example of what I would like to do. I tried to follow the documentation on `rpy2`'s website, but I can't seem to get it to work. This code works natively in R. How do I translate it to `rpy2`?

```
library(brms) 
data("kidney", package = "brms") 
head(kidney, n = 3)

fit1 <- brm(time | cens(censored) ~ age + sex + disease, 
            data = kidney, family = weibull, inits = "0")
summary(fit1)  
plot(fit1)

fit2 <- brm(time | cens(censored) ~ age + sex + disease + (1|patient),
                data = kidney, family = weibull(), inits = "0",
                prior = set_prior("cauchy(0,2)", class = "sd"))
summary(fit2)  
plot(fit2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, every non-built-in attribute or object must be qualified with a namespace. Fortunately, in R *everything* is an object within implicit namespaces! Most new useRs may not know but built-in core libraries, `base`, `stats`, `utils`, are loaded with each session. So many everyday functions like `read.csv`, `data.frame`, and `lapply` are actually methods within libraries and can be called in Python's style with double-colon operator: `utils::read_csv()`, `base::lapply()`, `stats::lm()`. To find such libaries, in R check method's doc pages with `?` (i.e., `?lapply`) and find in upper left corner.

Therefore, simply retain all of your R syntax, of course, adhering to Python's syntax rules such as translating dot names and without the assignment `<-` operator. However, `rpy2` does not render graphs interactively, so you need to save plots as images to disk and `print` any console output. Also, one challenge may be the loading of built-in datasets. Below includes the *mtcars* load  from the built-in R *datasets* package. Hopefully it is translatable.

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr, data

# IMPORT R PACKAGES
base = importr('base')
utils = importr('utils')
datasets = importr('datasets')
stats = importr('stats', robject_translations={'as.formula': 'as_formula'})
graphics = importr('graphics')
grDevices = importr('grDevices')    
brms = importr('brms')

# LOADING DATA
# WORKING EXAMPLE: mtcars = data(datasets).fetch('mtcars')['mtcars']
kidney_df = data(brms).fetch('kidney')['kidney']
print(utils.head(kidney_df, n = 3))

# MODELING
formula1 = stats.as_formula("time | cens(censored) ~ age + sex + disease")
fit1 = brms.brm(formula1, data = kidney_df, family = "weibull", inits = "0")
print(stats.summary(fit1))

formula2 = stats.as_formula("time | cens(censored) ~ age + sex + disease + (1|patient)")    
fit2 <- brms.brm(formula2, data = kidney_df, family = "weibull", inits = "0",
                 prior = brms.set_prior("cauchy(0,2)", class = "sd"))
print(stats.summary(fit2))

# GRAPHING
grDevices.png('/path/to/plot1.png') 
graphics.plot(fit1)
grDevices.dev_off()

grDevices.png('/path/to/plot2.png') 
graphics.plot(fit2)
grDevices.dev_off()
```